# Deactivate SharePoint 2010 Mobile View

Tags: mobile, blackberry

I want to deactivate the mobile view for my BlackBerry at my SharePoint 2010 environment. I edited the config file and set isMobileDevice to false (Of course iis reset after changes). 
But there is no change on my mobile device. When I opened a SharePoint site on my BlackBerry, I see the mobile view. But I want to use the default sites.

```
    <!-- BlackBerry RIM Browser -->
<browser id="BlackBerry" parentID="Default">
    <identification>
        <userAgent match="BlackBerry(?'model'\d+)/(?'version'((?'major'\d+)(?'minor'\.\d+).(?'other'\d+)))" />
    </identification>
    <capabilities>
        <capability name="browser"                              value="BlackBerry" />
        <capability name="cookies"                              value="true" />
        <capability name="canInitiateVoiceCall"                 value="true" />
        <capability name="frames"                               value="false" />
        <capability name="ecmascriptversion"                    value="1.3" />
        <capability name="isColor"                              value="true" />
        <capability name="isMobileDevice"                       value="false" />
        <capability name="javascript"                           value="true" />
        <capability name="majorVersion"                         value="${major}" />
        <capability name="minorVersion"                         value="${minor}" />
        <capability name="requires303Redirect"                  value="true" />
        <capability name="requiresLeadingPageBreak"             value="true" />
        <capability name="requiresUniqueFilePathSuffix"         value="true" />
        <capability name="supportsAccesskeyAttribute"           value="false" />
        <capability name="supportsBold"                         value="true" />
        <capability name="supportsCss"                          value="true" />
        <capability name="supportsFontSize"                     value="true" />
        <capability name="supportsImageSubmit"                  value="true" />
        <capability name="supportsItalic"                       value="true" />
        <capability name="version"                              value="${version}" />
        <capability name="webPartMobileExpandCollapseDisabled"  value="true" />
    </capabilities>
</browser>
```

Comment: See also http://ppalakollu.blogspot.ru/2011/08/sharepoint-2010-disable-mobile-page.html

Comment: See also http://sharepointdreamer.com/category/development/mobile/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verify the user agent being sent to the server and ensure it matches the browser ID.  You can do this via IIS logs and match to your IP or, load up Fiddler and inspect the HTTP requests.

Also double check that you edit the file associated to the webapp you are accessing.